# lifecycle of keychain service in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

What's the lifecycle of the item stored in keychain service API?

I am using a standard keychain service to store a small data but the value does not seem to be reset even when I uninstalled the app and re-deploy on to simulator.

```
let query =  NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword,
                           key,
                           user,
                           value as Any,
                           kSecMatchLimit],
                  forKeys: [kSecClass as NSString,
                           kSecAttrService as NSString,
                           kSecAttrAccount as NSString,
                           kSecReturnData as NSString,
                           kSecMatchLimit as NSString
                           )

SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
```

Also, how is this different from iCloudkeychain? There is an option to sync up thru icloud using [`ksecattrsynchronizable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattrsynchronizable) in the query. Does that mean it will be a permanent keychain item locally store on the device if we choose not to synchronize it thru iCloud?

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question.

The item stored in keychain is not reset when you uninstall the app.

It is stored there until you explicitly delete it.

Comment: for me it was more like, try and error, i would like to know how it works. :)